# Why Date/Time statement in access returning no values?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Table has an **End_Date** column (**Datatype**: Date/time) with last date of every month

When I run the query I expect all records with End Date less than for example **31-Dec-2019**

```
Select * from Table where End_Date < 31/12/2019
```

But it returns no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with dates in Access, you need to ensure that they are wrapped in octothorpes ("#"):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE End_Date<#31/12/2019#
```

Regards,

Comment: Octothorpe!  A new vocabulary word.